# How can I get TeamCity to verify a generated file

Tags: teamcity

My TeamCity build runs my build successfully, but I need to verify it is generating a specific file.

Specifically I can run gradle assemble for Android, but I need to know if a specific .apk file is created and fail if not.

I've tried setting the apk as an artifact, but I cannot fail if artifact wasn't created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried setting the apk as an artifact, but I cannot fail if artifact wasn't created.

Create script (i.e. bash/perl/php etc) to test what you need and make if fail (return 0 as return code) when your requirement is not met. Then invoke this script as separate build step in your project.

Comment: I had hoped TeamCity has some sort of built in verify artifact ability, but apparently not. I've implemented your solution and it works well. Thank you.